# Group by day and get last seven days data with respect to time zone in MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb, timezone

I have lot of document that look like this.

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5bcf7d670a31a41b382823e2"), 
  "score" : 75
}
```

My backend language is java.
I use _id field to filter data by date.

I have a java method which give me Object_id with respect to timezone.

```
public static ObjectId getObjectId(String date, String fromTimeZone) {
  SimpleDateFormat formatterFrom = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
  formatterFrom.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(fromTimeZone));
  return new ObjectId(Long.toHexString(formatterFrom.parse(date).getTime() / 1000L) + "0000000000000000");
}
```

fromTimeZone could be something like .

```
GMT+08:00
UTC
Africa/Algiers
Europe/London etc.
```

Now i would like to add some charts on my application dashboard. so i need last 7 days data like this.

```
{date: Nov-01, score:75}
{date: Nov-02, score:75}
{date: Nov-03, score:75}
{date: Nov-04, score:75}
{date: Nov-05, score:75}
{date: Nov-06, score:75}
{date: Nov-07, score:75}
```

Since lot of users use different time zone, I really dont have any idea how to do that.

help please.

Comment: Is `getObjectId` some standard function somewhere, or something you wrote yourself?  Without details of that, I doubt this can be answered.

Comment: it my function idea from this: https://coderwall.com/p/jv-y9q/converting-a-date-to-a-mongo-objectid

Comment: Except the one you linked to doesn't use a time zone.  Please edit your question to include the code for the function you're actually using.  Thanks.

Comment: I think i have shown enough details and showing just pseudo code for that method. because that method is not my point the thing is that i have fully functional method that gave me object id by date string and tmezone. why are you interested in that method?

Comment: consider that method is giving you proper object id.

Comment: The point of the date-based object id approach is that it's predictable, and thus queryable based on the way the object id is created.  Since you're somehow applying time zone, then you're somehow mutating the way the value is represented in the object id.  Without knowing how that is being done, your question is unanswerable - I cannot reproduce your results from what you've provided.   Please read from the help center: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I have added method body, please take a look

Comment: Thanks! Now I can see that you're storing object ids that are based on the UTC equivalent timestamp for the date and timezone provided.  That is good with regard to querying over a UTC date range.  Is this the only thing you store? Or do you also store the original local time and/or time zone in the document?  You would need one of those to logically determine the local date in a given time zone.

Comment: no that is only thing i store.

Comment: I must miss something but if your ObjectId is based upon UTC you just need the current time and the timezone of the client. Then convert it to UTC and compute 6 days ago and you have bounds to convert into ObjectId.

Comment: its standard mongodb objectId. which contains date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to fetch the matching documents, group by date with timezone and sum the scores and output the document.

Fetch and format results

```
//Create Variables
String endDt = "2018-11-08 01:02:03";
String startDt = "2018-11-01 01:02:03";
String timeZone = "GMT+08:00";

//Query Filter
Bson query = Aggregates.match(Filters.and(
     Filters.lte("_id", getObjectId(endDt,timeZone)),
     Filters.gte("_id", getObjectId(startDt,timeZone ))
));

//Objectid to datetime expression
Document toDate = new Document("$toDate", "$_id");
Bson objectIdToDate = Aggregates.projection(Projections.fields(
     Projections.excludeId(),
     Projections.include("score"),
     Projections.computed("date", toDate)
));

//Date expression with timezone
Document dateExpression = Document.parse(
  "{'$dateFromParts':{
   'year':{'$year':{'date':'$date','timezone:'"+ timeZone +"}},
   'month':{'$month':{'date':'$date','timezone':"+ timeZone +"}},
   'day':{'$dayOfMonth':{'date':'$date','timezone':"+ timeZone +"}}
   }}"
);

//Group by Date
Bson group = Aggregates.group(new Document("$_id", dateExpression), Accumlators.sum("score", "$score"));

//final output
Bson fields = Aggregates.projection(Projections.fields(
     Projections.excludeId(),
     Projections.include("score"),
     Projections.computed("date", "$_id")
));

//Fetch matching records
AggregateIterable<Document> iterable = collection.aggregate(Arrays.asList(query,objectIdToDate,group,fields));

//Format results
for(Document document:iterable) {
    document.put("date", formatDateToMonthDay(date)); 
}
```

Helper Methods

```
public static String formatDateToMonthDay(Date date) {
    DateTimeFormattter monthDayFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM-dd");
    Instant instant = date.toInstant();
    return instant.format(monthDayFormatter); 
}

public ObjectId getObjectId(String date, String fromTimeZone) {
    DateTimeFormattter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(date,formatter);
    Instant instant = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(instant, ZoneId.of(fromTimeZone)).toInstant();
    return new ObjectId(Long.toHexString(instant.getEpochSecond()) + "0000000000000000");
}
```